# User will input some filter criteria -- how can I turn it into a regular expression for String.match

Tags: java, regex

I have a program where the user will enter a string such as 
`PropertyA = "abc_*"` and I need to have the asterisk match any character.

In my code, I'm grabbing the property value and replacing `PropertyA` with the actual value. For instance, it could be `abc_123`. I also pull out the equality symbol into a variable.

It should be able to cover this type of criteria

> PropertyB = 'cba'
>
> PropertyC != '*-this'

`valueFromHeader` is the lefthand side and `value` is the righthand side.

```
if (equality.equals("=")) {
    result = valueFromHeader.matches(value);
} else if (equality.equals("!=")) {
    result = !valueFromHeader.matches(value);
}
```

EDIT:

The existing code had this type of replacement for regular expressions

```
    final String ESC = "\\$1";
    final String NON_ALPHA = "([^A-Za-z0-9@])";
    final String WILD = "*";
    final String WILD_RE_TEMP = "@";
    final String WILD_RE = ".*";
    value = value.replace(WILD, WILD_RE_TEMP);
    value = value.replaceAll(NON_ALPHA,ESC);
    value = value.replace(WILD_RE_TEMP, WILD_RE);
```

It doesn't like the underscore here...

```
abcSite_123 != abcSite_123 (evaluates to true)
abcSite_123$1.matches("abcSite$1123")
```

It doesn't like the underscore...

Comment: What isn't working with what you have tried so far?

Comment: Please include your entire method, and state what isn't working.

Comment: I replaced the original problem with some existing code that was already present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `*` with `.*`..

```
value=value.replace("*",".*");//replace  * with .*
```

This won't work if your value contain `+`,`?` since they all have special meaning in regex.Escape them if their are any..

Comment: When testing this, if I give it `abcSite != 'abc*'` I get `abcSite != \Qabc*\E `and it evaluates to True (based on the if statement which negates the matching).

Comment: Just to logically make it easier to make sure my logic is alright, I tried `abcSite = 'abc*'` and it evaluates as `false`

Comment: That worked! Let me test it against some more input.